# FIRMessaging - Limit 1 topic or check signed up topics

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I looked through the documentation regarding this and couldn't find anything. Is there a way to see what topics the user is signed up for? Or a way to limit it to 1 topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for getting the list of topics within the Firebase Cloud Messaging API. But if you're willing to run server-side code, you can [use the Instance ID REST API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server?utm_campaign=Firebase_announcement_awareness_fcm_en_10-17-16&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=blog#get_information_about_app_instances) directly:

> ## Example GET request
>
> ```
> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...clJONHoA?details=true
> Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
> ```
>
> ## Example result
>
> ```
> HTTP 200 OK
> {
>   "application":"com.iid.example",
>   "authorizedEntity":"123456782354",
>   "platform":"Android",
>   "attestStatus":"ROOTED",
>   "appSigner":"1a2bc3d4e5",
>   "connectionType":"WIFI",
>   "connectDate":"2015-05-12
>   "rel":{
>     "topics":{
>       "topicname1":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"},
>       "topicname2":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"},
>       "topicname3":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"},
>       "topicname4":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"}
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```